# Print additional lines after completing a search

Tags: python-3.x

I have a txt file with a lot of information I don't need. The program below works on most of the file. My problem is, when I find the line that has `"OB"`, I want to print all the lines `after "OB" and before "CB"`. I don't know what the lines contain, so I can't search for them, and there may be 1 line in between or 25 lines in between the line with `"OB" and "CB"`.

Is this too confusing?

```
f=open('temp.txt','r')
f1=open('newtemp.txt', 'a')

a ='PN'
b = 'OB'
c = 'CB'

for line in f.readlines():
    if a in line:
        print (line)
    if b in line:
        print (line)
    if c in line:
        print (line)       


f1.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: in given example `f1` is never used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
f = open('temp.txt','r')
f1 = open('newtemp.txt', 'a')

a ='PN'
b = 'OB'
c = 'CB'

flag = False

for line in f.readlines():

    if b in line:            
        flag = True
        continue

    if flag:
        if c not in line:
            print (line)       
        else:
            break

f1.close()
f.close()
```

This is just to give you an idea on how to solve the problem. Note that in this example I didn't use the `a` and `f1` variables.

Answer (score 0):

The following will read the line one line at a time, test whether `b` ("OB") is in the line, then stop reading, continue reading in a next loop until it encounters a line with `c` ("CB") in it. No flag needed; it simply relies on the file pointer moving forwards per line.

```
fname = 'temp.txt'
b = 'OB'
c = 'CB'

with open(fname) as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if b in line:
            break
    for line in fp:
        if c in line:
            break
        print(line)
```